# php is not recognized as an internal command (in Windows)

Tags: php, windows, cmd

I want to develop using a framework called Symfony but I do not have a Mac and I don't want to dual boot with Debian.

I tried virtual hosts via Virtual Box but it doesn't work. So I decided to stay on Windows.

So when the tutorial tells me to do

```
php lib/vendor/symfony/data/bin/check_configuration.php
```

i do in the windows cmd :

```
php lib\vendor\symfony\data\bin\check_configuration.php
```

and it tells me:

> 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command

I use UwAmp (php 5.2.12 + mysql + apache) which is stored in

```
E:\logiciels\UwAmp\
```

inside I have bunch of files, but I guess that is important:

```
E:\logiciels\UwAmp\apache\php_5.2.11
```

How to make the cmd PHP in the windows cmd work properly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll have to add the directory in which the php executable is located to your "path" variable (I guess in your case that would be E:\logiciels\UwAmp\apache\php_5.2.11
). In Windows, you can do that as described here: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Any directory you place in this path variable (they're separated by a semicolon) will be automatically used in, for example, a cmd shell.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;E:\logiciels\UwAmp\apache\php_5.2.11 <------------- that's how it looks now

Comment: php.exe is really in "E:\logiciels\UwAmp\apache\php_5.2.11" and not in a subdirectory of it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the path where the binary resides in to the PATH variable. You can do this on XP and Win 7 under the System -> User settings -> User variables