# How to use command line in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am learning Symfony, so I have only gotten to

> Symfony/web/app_dev.php/demo/

But I'm still not able to find how to use command line.

I have shell access, but where to execute this command?

```
php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Blogger/BlogBundle --format=yml
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That command is meant to be run from your root symfony folder. If you have everything installed correctly, you should see the app directory listed when you use the `ls` command. If you don't see the app directory, either you didn't install correctly or your in the wrong folder on your system.

Comment: Also if you are on windows, make sure you set php path like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920903/php-is-not-recognized-as-an-intern-command-using-windows#answer-2920927)

Answer (score 0):

execute from root folder. The "console" (its a php file with no extension) file is in app/ folder. You can also go into that folder and run:

```
php console generate:bundle --namespace=Blogger/BlogBundle --format=yml
```