# Run .php file in Windows Command Prompt (cmd)

Tags: php, cmd

I want to run a `.php` file in windows cmd.
I followed this (suggestion)
[php is not recognized as an internal command (in Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920903/php-is-not-recognized-as-an-intern-command-using-windows)

But it did not work.

I tried this command prompt:
 `C:\Windows\system32> cd \myfolder`

And within `myfolder` I did as follows:
`C:..\myfolder> php file.php`
but I get an error "php is not recognized as internal or external"

But when I try without `php` command like this;
 `C:..\myfolder> file.php`
 
it just opens in notepad, yet I want to run it in `cmd`.
 How can I do it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**If running Windows 10:**

1. Open the start menu
2. Type `path`
3. Click ***Edit the system environment variables*** (usually, it's the top search result) and continue on step **6** below.

**If on older Windows:**

1. Show Desktop.
2. Right Click ***My Computer*** shortcut in the desktop.
3. Click ***Properties***.
4. You should see a section of control Panel - ***Control Panel\System and Security\System***.
5. Click ***Advanced System Settings*** on the Left menu.
6. Click ***Enviornment Variables*** towards the bottom of the *System Properties* window.
7. Select ***PATH*** in the user variables list.
8. Append your PHP Path (C:\myfolder\php) to your PATH variable, separated from the already existing string by a semi colon.
9. Click OK
10. Open your "cmd"
11. Type PATH, press enter
12. Make sure that you see your PHP folder among the list.

That should work.

Note: Make sure that your PHP folder has the php.exe. It should have the file type CLI. If you do not have the php.exe, go ahead and check the installation guidelines at - http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.manual.php - and download the installation file from there.

Comment: Thanks i have done all of this. But what about the php.exe  file. I havn't it. 
Is it need to convert php file as .exe ?

Comment: When you type "php file.php", the first php is actually the php.exe, command line tool. Just edited the answer. Please check

Comment: ok, what i have done. my path is C:\myfolder\file.php 
I edit variable path with another path like ( .;path;C:\myfolder )
And i typed in cmd C:\Windows\system32>cd \myfolder 
and get my folder and showing in cmd like C:\myfolder> 
and then  i type C:\myfolder>php file.php 
then it just showing  "php is not recognized as internal or external"

what i need to do ?

Comment: Go to http://windows.php.net/download/ , download an installer first. Then, install PHP in your machine by clicking the installer. Then find out the path in which the PHP was installed. Follow my instructions and add the PHP path to the PATH variable

Comment: I have wamp installed in my pc. is it enough or need to install that ? ( i have already download it . )

Comment: Wamp is fine - Then, your PHP folder will be somethng like - <path to wamp installtion>\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8

Comment: ok, i typed : cd C:\wamp\\bin\php\php5.3.5 ( my version id 5.3.5 ) then it just gone to that folder in CMD Like : C:\wamp\\bin\php\php5.3.5  .
so, now ?

Comment: php <path to your phpfile>\file.php  (This could very well have been another question. LOL

Comment: Nice it's working. Thanks. 
But it's just showing my php code in CMD.

Comment: Suppose, work of my php script is search a file. 
but in this method php script showing in cmd console but how can i work here ?

Comment: Run "php -i" without file arguments. That should show you the PHP configurations. If it doesn't, there is some issue with your WAMP installation

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17967/discussion-between-user1687804-and-janenz00)

Comment: OK, I have just copied that php.exe from wamp folder. And now i can from my directory. Thanks.

Comment: @user1687804: I suggest you to edit your post and notify about your above comment which guide to copy the `php.exe` to another folder , that's very helpful .

Answer (score 3):

you can for example: set your environment variable path with php.exe folder e.g c:\program files\php

create a script file in d:\ with filename as a.php

open cmd: go to d: drive using d: command

type following command

php -f a.php

you will see the output

Answer (score 1):

You should declare Environment Variable for PHP in path, so you could use like this:

```
C:\Path\to\somewhere>php cli.php
```

You can do it like [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx)

Comment: Tired it but it just showing error "php is not recognized as internal or external"

Comment: Are you sure php was correctly installed?... Type 'php -v' on your terminal to confirm

Answer (score 0):

It seems your question is very much older. But I just saw it.
I searched(not in google) and found My Answer.

So I am writing its solution so that others may get help from it.

Here is my solution.

**Unlike** the other answers, you don't need to setup environments.

all you need is just to write `php index.php` if `index.php` is your file name.

then you will see that, the file compiled and showing it's desired output.