# How to install Laravel via installer?

Tags: laravel

In Laravel documentation, it explained one short paragraph on how to use installer to install Laravel.

> First, download the Laravel installer PHAR archive. For convenience, rename the file to laravel and move it to /usr/local/bin. Once installed, the simple laravel new command will create a fresh Laravel installation in the directory you specify. For instance, laravel new blog would create a directory named blog containing a fresh Laravel installation with all dependencies installed. This method of installation is much faster than installing via Composer.

I am a Windows 7 user. After download the `laravel.phar` file, where should I store the file? I don't think there is any `/usr/local/bin` directory on Windows 7. How can I get the `laravel` command to be able to use in command window?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Laravel 4.1 in Windows 7 // Make .phar file globally available to windows command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829129/installing-laravel-4-1-in-windows-7-make-phar-file-globally-available-to-win)

Answer (score 2):

Install laravel 5.2 via Laravel Installer in windows 7

Steps:

1. Please make sure you have installed composer into your computer
2. Open command prompt
3. $ composer global require “laravel/installer”
4. C:\xampp\htdocs> laravel new mylaravel

Youtube video guide:
http://www.pranms.com/how-to-install-laravel-5-2-via-laravel-installer-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 1):

The laravel installer needs to be in your PATH (no matter which Operating system).

In Unix based systems, /usr/local/bin is in your PATH by default.

On Windows, you can add a folder to your PATH by doing like this:

> - Start the System Control Panel applet (Start - Settings - Control Panel - System).
> - Select the Advanced tab.
> - Click the Environment Variables button.
> - Under System Variables, select Path, then click Edit.
>
> From http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-add-new-folder-my-system-path

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier to install using Composer. Download the Windows Composer installer from the [Composer Website](http://getcomposer.org) and run it. Once it's installed you can run from the command line:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name
```

This will create the folder *your-project-name* and install Laravel in it. The advantage of using Composer it that it makes adding other packages to Laravel really easy.

Comment: I think having both composer and the laravel tool is even better. Especially if you create laravel projects often.