# phpunit command doesn't work for laravel 4 on windows 7

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

I've recently installed laravel and have written some tests in /tests directory but when I use `phpunit` at cmd in the same folder that `phpunit.xml` exists, it says `'phpunit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`. I'm using windows 7. what should I do?

Comment: Yes I mean installed it

Comment: Did you set the environmental variable?

Comment: Environment variables for what?

Comment: To be able to run commands with `phpunit`. It was working before?

Comment: no it wasn't , so you mean I should add the phpunit executable to PATH yeah?

Comment: Big yes! If it isn't already. Try `echo %PATH%` in cmd and see the output contain `phpunit`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The solution for me:

```
php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
```

This, of course, assumes you've [set up a php environment variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870880/run-php-file-in-windows-cmd)

Answer (score 21):

As Unnawut said, it doesn't work because vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit is not a native Windows executable. You need a .bat or .cmd file that will basically call 'php phpunit'.   There should be one in vendor/bin, but to make life easy, try this - create a file phpunit.bat (or .cmd) at the root of your site, containing this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET BIN_TARGET=%~dp0/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
php "%BIN_TARGET%" %*
```

Now you can call phpunit from the command line at the root of the site.

Answer (score 12):

If you are a window user and you are having this issue, do this:

You need to tell Window where to find PHPUnit command, you can first of all verify that this file exists in your Laravel project under /vendor/bin

[image]

Finally you need to append the full path to `/vendor/bin` in your window PATH variable,

To do this:
1. Right-click on 'Computer' then click properties

[image]

2. On the second window click `Advanced system settings`

[image]

3. On the next window under `Advanced` click `Environmental Variables`

[image]

4. On the next window double-click `PATH` then set PATH variable by appending

the full path to your `laravel-project/vendor/bin;` Notice the `;` at the end.

NB: Other variables might already exists in the PATH, so ensure you don't overwrite them by appending your own at the very end

5. Finally click `Ok` on all the dialog boxes

[image]

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. Solves my problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
alias phpunit="vendor/bin/phpunit"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 4):

I added this command in command line instead of just **"phpunit"**

```
vendor\bin\phpunit
```

That worked for me.

Comment: I explained a bit more  :)

Comment: Or you can add `./vendor/bin` to the PATH environment variable. This way you can just call `phpunit` from any Laravel root folder.

Comment: @ArnovanOordtPlease submit your comment as an answer to this question. It easy to implement, is permanent and has global scope. It is the best answer here and deserves it's own post.

Answer (score 4):

Install `phpunit` globally:

```
composer global require phpunit/phpunit
```

Afterwards you will be able to run `phpunit` ( even on Windows ):

```
phpunit
```

Answer (score 3):

The phpunit executable is not in your project root folder, that's why it can't find it.

Now I assume that you already have phpunit in your `composer.json` file, something like this:

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*"
}
```

When installed by composer, the package will be installed to `vendor/vendor_name/package_name`. So to run it at your project root, type this command:

```
vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
```

Comment: `composer update` and after that do `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit` from the folder you have `phpunit.xml`

Comment: Oh well I guess that's as far as I could help. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This working for me

In double quotes this command in console windows

"vendor/bin/phpunit"

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from @Chris' [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25474770/5023488):
Even better, you can make `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit` an [environment variable](https://www.itechtics.com/create-custom-environment-variables-windows-10/), say "phpunit" and whenever you want to run the test in any laravel project you just call `php %phpunit%`.

### Demonstration

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it says the following:

$ phpunit tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php
PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Class 'tests/Feature/ExampleTest' could not be found in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\blog1\tests\Feature\ExampleTest.php'.

Instead of typing tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php  you say tests " \\Feature\\Example.test" because you're using windows, not mac. :) GL & HF

Using just \ or / will give errors :)

Comment: It wasn't saying that. The error message was something else

Answer (score 0):

With Laravel phpunit is set up right out of the box.  The easiest way to run it on Windows is to add an entry to scripts in your package.json file...

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "tests": "php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit"
},
```

Now you simply run unit tests with

```
npm run tests
```