# PHPUnit not working with Laravel 5

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-5

I just installed a fresh Laravel 5 project, my first one on this version. PHPUnit is supposed to be out of the box with the framework and every tutorials I saw just say to type `phpunit` within the project folder to launch the Unit Tests.

I checked and PHPUnit is in the `composer.json`, I also did a `composer install` and `composer update` just in case it wouldn't be here

```
website(master)$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing phpunit/phpunit (4.6.1)
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit (4.6.2)
    Downloading: 100%
```

But it just doesn't work `phpunit` isn't recognized at all

```
 website(master)$ phpunit
-bash: phpunit: command not found
```

Seems like nobody got this problem before as I Googled it. I hope I'm not doing any stupid mistake. Any idea or suggestion ? Thanks guys ;)

Comment: `./vendor/bin/phpunit`

Comment: @Laurent it's not uncommon to have PHPUnit installed globally on your system so you can run `phpunit` from anywhere

Comment: Yeah I installed it globally and it works well now

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I didn't install PHPUnit globally and didn't define the path. So for anyone who would have same problem :

```
composer global require phpunit/phpunit
composer global require phpunit/dbunit
```

Then you add this to you `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`

```
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: For anyone using phpunit globally: might this approach have the downside of always testing with the same version of phpunit VS testing with the one defined by the project composer.json file (as the answer of atul_systematix states)? Or isn't this really an issue to worry about?

Answer (score 17):

This occurs when you don't have phpunit installed globally.

Run this command to use the local version (installed with composer):

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 11):

in windows machine the command is different please use this command

```
php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
```

[orignal source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24345264/phpunit-command-doesnt-work-for-laravel-4-on-windows-7)

Comment: How we can make it less as it is very long,do you know any way to do this in Windows 10?

Answer (score 3):

You can run this command in `cmd` before running `phpunit` command:

```sh
doskey phpunit="vendor/bin/phpunit"
```

And if you are lazy as I am, you can run this one:

```sh
doskey pu="vendor/bin/phpunit"
```

Comment: after restarting cmd I have to repeat this command, how make it work for everytime?

Comment: Yes dude, don't be lazy as I am and run the command before each new cmd session  ;)

Comment: doskey on Windows is very similar to alias on Linux

Answer (score 2):

for people who have WINDOWS 7, use the `.\vendor\bin\phpunit` command instead of `./vendor/bin/phpunit`

Answer (score 0):

Run the command

```
composer config --list --global | grep -w home
```

You can find the find the `[home]` with composer path, similar to this one.

```
[home] /home/example_username/.config/composer
```

The path `~/.config/composer` is where composer global packages are installed. Next run the command...

```
export PATH=~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a permanent link to my phpunit like this

```
echo 'alias phpunit=vendor/bin/phpunit' >> ~/.bash_aliases
```

now `phpunit` is working by itself and stays even after I restart the terminal

Answer (score -1):

Include this line on your composer.json

```
"phpunit/phpunit": "4.0.*",
```

Run composer update.
You should be able to run the following command on your Laravel directory.

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```