# How can i use command line to connect to our website in windows

Tags: php, windows, command-line

I want to use this command to run this file of our website

**php -f /shell/Namespace/ProductExport.php**

How can I connect in windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run php file in windows CMD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870880/run-php-file-in-windows-cmd)

Comment: No, the file is not in my computer, It is on server where our website is hosted. If you know please tell me which software to use

Comment: there are many solutions to connect with a windows server, `remote desktop`, `vnc` or `teamviewer`. First, connect with your server and then follow the already answered post.

if you are connecting with linux server, you can use `putty`.

Comment: yes actually i downloaded putty but due to its weird copy paste option i was getting access denied

But everything is working fine now

Thank you for your help