# 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: php, cakephp-2.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [‘php.exe’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464315/php-exe-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program)

I am trying to setup a cakePHP installation on my computer using WAMP.

I am facing problems while trying to setup the path of the installation. Here are the Path entries that I have made.

```
F:\ProgrammingPoint\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3;F:\ProgrammingPoint\wamp\www\cake\app\Console;
```

each for the PHP and the cakePHP installation . However when I try the cake bake command as:

```
F:\ProgrammingPoint\wamp\www\cake\app\Console cake bake
```

I get the following error.

```
'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

Output of set path is :

```
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x8
6)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:
\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:
\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\O
penCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Componen
ts\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Progr
am Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
(x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bl
uetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program
 Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

Comment: What happens if you run `php`?

Comment: Check the output of `set path` if the path is correctly set. If you have set the PATH-variable using the `Environment Variables` Dialog you probably have to close and re-open the console, since only new processes inherit the new environment variables.

Comment: sounds like php isn't properly set.

Comment: @vstm: `set path` returns the above. Which is weird because Ive set Path as I described in the question

Comment: Just make sure you have added PHP to your Envoirnment Variable's path. For example i would set C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13.

Answer (score -3):

You have to install Cake php where php executable file is located.

Your file should be(?) in `F:\ProgrammingPoint\wamp\apache\php_5.2.11`....

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920903/php-is-not-recognized-as-an-intern-command-using-windows).

Comment: Ive edited the question . Could you please explain wrt to setting the path correctly?